# Checking for words inside folders/subfolders and files

Tags: ruby, regex

I am having issue with regular expressions. So basically I have a folder and this folder contains sub folders as well as files. I have to check for certain words in those folders. The words I have to check for are located in a file called `words.txt` file.

This is the code that I have so far in Ruby:

```
def check_words
  array_of_words = File.readlines('words.txt')
  re = Regexp.union(array_of_words)
  new_array_of_words = [/\b(?:#{re.source})\b/]

  Dir['source_test/**/*'].select{|f| File.file?(f) }.each do |filepath|
    new_array_of_words.each do |word| 
     puts File.foreach(filepath).include?(word)
    end 
  end
end
```

When I execute this code I keep getting `false` even though some of the files inside the folders/subfolders contains those words.

Comment: Please tag the language that you're using

Comment: Sorry Ruby Language

Answer (score 0):

`new_array_of_words` is a single regex, and the `include?` methods acts on strings (and it doesn't make much sense to iterate over a single regex anyway).

You can keep using the regex, but use [regex methods instead](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html).

You can also fix your current code as follows:

```
arr = File.readlines('/home/afifit/Tests/word.txt')
arr.select { |e| e.strip! }

Dir['yourdir/*'].select{|f| File.file?(f) }.each do |filepath|
    arr.each do |word| 
     puts File.foreach(filepath).include?(word)
    end 
  end
```

I also used `strip` to remove any unnecessary whitespaces and newlines.

Comment: [Picture of the code and Output](http://i.imgur.com/V9LVSCp.png)

So implemented the code you suggested and I still get false for all the files that have been checked

Comment: Try and use the regex as following: `File.foreach(filepath) do |w| re.match(w) end`.

Comment: Define the regular expression as you did in the OP. Also you don't need to iterate over the array any more.

Comment: [Error](http://i.imgur.com/UAzLdVq.png), @afifit I think I implemented what you said above correctly, but the method returns a Enumerator object.